# Showing the last two years worth of SQL data in chart.js line graph, up to the present day

Tags: php, chart.js

I've got a line chart that basically shows spend against budgets and it works like this:

I've got an include that contains the following, which prepares the data for display:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli(blah blah blah);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $year = date('Y');
    $total=array();
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month ++){
        $sql="SELECT *, SUM(Contracts.Sum_Approved) AS total FROM Contracts JOIN Budgets ON Contracts.Budget = Budgets.BudgetID WHERE month(Contracts.Decision_Date)='$month' AND year(Contracts.Decision_Date)='$year' AND Contracts.owner=$userid AND Contracts.Archived=0 AND Contracts.Budget=$budget";
        $query=$conn->query($sql);
        $row=$query->fetch_array();

        $total[]=$row['total'];
    }

    $tjan = $total[0];
    $tfeb = $total[1];
    $tmar = $total[2];
    $tapr = $total[3];
    $tmay = $total[4];
    $tjun = $total[5];
    $tjul = $total[6];
    $taug = $total[7];
    $tsep = $total[8];
    $toct = $total[9];
    $tnov = $total[10];
    $tdec = $total[11];

    $pyear = $year - 1;
    $pnum=array();

    for ($pmonth = 1; $pmonth <= 12; $pmonth ++){
        $sql="SELECT *, SUM(Contracts.Sum_Approved) AS ptotal FROM Contracts JOIN Budgets ON Contracts.Budget = Budgets.BudgetID WHERE month(Contracts.Decision_Date)='$pmonth' AND year(Contracts.Decision_Date)='$pyear' AND Contracts.owner=$userid AND Contracts.Archived=0 AND Contracts.Budget=$budget";
        $pquery=$conn->query($sql);
        $prow=$pquery->fetch_array();

        $ptotal[]=$prow['ptotal'];
    }

    $pjan = $ptotal[0];
    $pfeb = $ptotal[1];
    $pmar = $ptotal[2];
    $papr = $ptotal[3];
    $pmay = $ptotal[4];
    $pjun = $ptotal[5];
    $pjul = $ptotal[6];
    $paug = $ptotal[7];
    $psep = $ptotal[8];
    $poct = $ptotal[9];
    $pnov = $ptotal[10];
    $pdec = $ptotal[11];
```

Pretty basic stuff - just getting the current year's data plus the previous year's data.

I then draw the chart using:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Feb <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Mar <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Apr <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "May <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Jun <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Jul <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Aug <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Sep <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Oct <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Nov <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Dec <?php echo date("Y") - 1; ?>", "Jan  <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Feb <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Mar <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Apr <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "May <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Jun <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Jul <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Aug <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Sep <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Oct <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Nov <?php echo date("Y"); ?>", "Dec <?php echo date("Y"); ?>"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Agreed Funding",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointRadius: 3,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
          data                : [ "<?php echo $pjan; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pfeb; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pmar; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $papr; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pmay; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pjun; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pjul; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $paug; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $psep; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $poct; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pnov; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $pdec; ?>",

                                  "<?php echo $tjan; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tfeb; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tmar; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tapr; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tmay; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tjun; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tjul; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $taug; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tsep; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $toct; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tnov; ?>",
                                  "<?php echo $tdec; ?>"
                                ],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 25,
        top: 25,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          padding: 10,
          // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '£' + number_format(value);
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [2],
          zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      titleMarginBottom: 10,
      titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
      titleFontSize: 14,
      borderColor: '#dddfeb',
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
      caretPadding: 10,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
          var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
          return datasetLabel + ': £' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This all works fine. However, the dates are obviously fixed and static. So Jan to Dec of the previous year, and Jan to Dec of the current year.

But how would I go about showing the last two year's data, with the final point being today? So rather than having a fixed range, it's more dynamic and based on today's date.

Hopefully that makes sense.

I guess I could do some basic if statements when outputting data, and essentially template out all 12 possible output combinations, but it seems a bit clunky?

Comment: Why are you stuffing all of these values into individually named variables to begin with - instead of putting them into an array? With an array, you could just use `json_encode` to create a representation that JS can “read” in one go.

Comment: It was mostly me trying to get my head around Chart.js, which I've never used before, and wanting to be clear exactly what's working and what's not. I will most likely switch to an array once I've got everything working.

Comment: Using an array _is_ part of solving this without any larger `if` constructs. What you need to pass for `data`, in the place where you are currently operating with all your individual, named variables, appears to be just a JavaScript array anyway - that has no connection of the data to any specific month any more anyway, that is just 24 values one after the other. So gather your 24 data points in a _PHP_ array to begin with, then all you need to create the correct output in the JS part, is `data: <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>`

Comment: I'm already sticking the data in an array $total, but I was having problems when outputting this to the receiving JS. So I can output <?php echo json_encode($total); ?>, but it seemingly breaks the JS because of the inclusion of non-quoted NULL values.

Comment: How exactly are those a problem? JavaScript itself should not have a problem parsing those. If your library doesn’t want to accept `null` values, that might be a different issue - one only circumvented by your current solution because `echo` of a NULL value in PHP only results in an empty string as output. But you could still loop over that array yourself in that place, to output all your values inside of double quotes, you don’t have to use json_encode for it.